# insertar valores de una tabla en otra

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, set

Tengo una tabla `tb_invoice` con las siguientes columnas:

- invoice_id
- line_id
- line_num
- item
- description
- ...

Por otra parte, tengo otra tabla vacía `tb_item` que contiene las columnas

- item_id
- item
- description

Quiero hacer un insert en la tabla `tb_item` a partir del select de `tb_lines` con varias condiciones:

1. item sea distinto de cero
2. orden de la description descendiente

El valor de `item_id` viene dado por una secuencia previamente creada.

El código que tengo es este:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE erp.seq_item_id INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 90001 NO CYCLE;

WITH seleccion AS (
    SELECT item, description 
    FROM erp.tb_lines 
    WHERE item IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY description DESC
)

INSERT INTO erp.tb_item AS tbi
SET item_id = nextval('erp.seq_item_id')
FROM seleccion AS sel              
where tbi.item = sel.item;
```

El error que me muestra es el siguiente:

```
ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «SET»
LINE 9: SET item_id = nextval('erp.seq_item_id')
```

He probado con `SET` y con `VALUES` siguiendo la [documentación de postgre](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html), pero no encuentro la forma adecuada de que funcione.

Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias

Comment: puedes mostrar que error/mensaje te muestra al poner values

Comment: el error es exactamente el mismo , ```ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «VALUES»```

Comment: vale, pero te lo digo porque estas comparando en el insert sin que este en la clausula where, si ya estas comparando aqui where tbi.item = sel.item;, porque poner esto tambien item_id = nextval('erp.seq_item_id'), otra cosa no veo que selecciones seq_item_id en el codigo que esta el with

Comment: perdona pero no entiendo lo que me dices en la respuesta. hago la comparación ``` where tbi.item = sel.item;``` ,y entonces qué quieres decir con `porque poner esto tambien item_id = nextval('erp.seq_item_id'), otra cosa no veo que selecciones seq_item_id en el codigo que esta el with'? ```seq_item_id``` lo tengo creado previamente y funciona bien pero puedo añadirlo en la consulta

Comment: si sustituyo el ```SET``` por un ```WHERE```, el error continúa: ```error de sintaxis en o cerca de «WHERE»```. Además, la tabla tiene 2 columnas diferentes: item e item_id, por eso incluyo una en la cláusula ```WHERE``` y la de item_id es la que quiero que esté asignada con la secuencia.

Comment: Pero el where no tenias que quitarlo sino el set que estas poniendo, si, pero en una consulta tienes que hacer select al campo estando creado sino no vas a poder obtener su valor, si tu no haces un select de un campo y lo quieres comparar , en la parte del set si en vez de poner nextval poner un entero cualquiera te da error?